# XSL: How to concatenate nodes with conditions?

Tags: xslt, foreach

I have the following code (eg):

```
<response>
  <parameter>
    <cottage>
      <cot>
       <res>
        <hab desc="Lakeside">
          <reg cod="OB" prr="600.84>
            <lwz>TR#2#AB#200.26#0#QB#OK#20120829#20120830#EU#3-0#</lwz>
            <lwz>TR#2#AB#200.26#0#QB#OK#20120830#20120831#EU#3-0#</lwz>
            <lwz>TR#2#AB#200.26#0#QB#OK#20120831#20120901#EU#3-0#</lwz>
```

I need to create a concatenated string that includes the whole of the first 'lwz' line and then the price (200.26, but it can be different in each line) for each corresponding line.

So the output, separating each line with | would be:

TR#2#AB#200.26#0#QB#OK#20120829#20120830#EU#3-0#|200.26|200.26

Thanks

Comment: There is no element named "lin". Please, provide a wellformed source XML document. Also provide the exact wanted output and any explanations about rules/constraints for the transformation.

Comment: Oops; edited the question. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answers for two complete solutions.

Comment: @S_Q_H: Was my answer useful?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply. Yes, very helpful; thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="lwz[1]">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="lwz[position() >1]">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat('&#xA;',
              substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(.,'#'),'#'),'#'),'#')
          )
     "/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided text** (converted to a well-formed XML document !!!):

```
<response>
    <parameter>
        <cottage>
            <cot>
                <res>
                    <hab desc="Lakeside">
                        <reg cod="OB" prr="600.84">
                            <lwz>TR#2#AB#200.26#0#QB#OK#20120829#20120830#EU#3-0#</lwz>
                            <lwz>TR#2#AB#200.26#0#QB#OK#20120830#20120831#EU#3-0#</lwz>
                            <lwz>TR#2#AB#200.26#0#QB#OK#20120831#20120901#EU#3-0#</lwz>
                        </reg>
                    </hab>
                </res>
            </cot>
        </cottage>
    </parameter>
</response>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
TR#2#AB#200.26#0#QB#OK#20120829#20120830#EU#3-0#
200.26
200.26
```

**II XSLT 2.0 solution**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="lwz[1]">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="lwz[position() >1]">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat('&#xA;', tokenize(.,'#')[4])"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the above XML document, again produces the wanted, correct result. Note the use of the standard XPath 2.0 function [`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize):**

```
TR#2#AB#200.26#0#QB#OK#20120829#20120830#EU#3-0#
200.26
200.26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256054.aspx) function to select substrings from your `lwz` node data. You don't really give much more detail about your problem, if you want a more detailed answer, perhaps provide the full XML document and your best-guess XSLT